# JS, How can understood page is refreshed or first time opened?

Tags: javascript, browser, load, refresh

Using javascript possible understood if page is load witch refresh button or `F5` key? that is JS can make something like this?

```
            if (/*   page is load wich browser "refresh" button or "F5" key   */) {
                alert("page is refreshed");
            }
            else if (/*    we coming here from other page    */) {
                alert("We coming here from other page");
            }
```

Comment: maybe using cookies will help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `document.referrer` property, but note that it will be blank both when the page is refreshed *and* when the user arrived at the page via a bookmark or by typing the URL directly in the browser address bar (and possibly if they have a browser extension blocking referrer information). It will normally have a value when the user has clicked a link to get to the page. So it's imperfect, but I don't know that there's anything better without doing server-side stuff.